# Do tokenizers remove whitespaces?

Tags: lucene, tokenize, stringtokenizer

Does Lucene's Standard Tokenizer remove whitespaces and blank lines? I've been reading the API ([StandardTokenizer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html)) but it's not specified. Maybe tokenizers do it by default, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Lucene tokenizers grab indexable terms from documents, which does not include whitespace. They do preserve the token's offsets in the original document, though.

This is documented in the docs for [`StandardTokenizer`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardTokenizer.html):

- Splits words at punctuation characters, removing punctuation.

(Whitespace is punctuation.)

Comment: blank lines are considered whitespaces too?

Comment: @Kits89: yep, any whitespace is.